# Loading scATAC-seq data containing matrix.mtx, fragments.tsv and barcodes.tsv files from GEO into R?

Tags: seurat, single-cell, 10x-genomics, atac-seq

I want to analyse the single-cell ATAC-seq data from 10X downloaded from GSE158398. The files attached to this dataset are `matrix.mtx.gz`, `fragments.tsv.gz`, and `barcodes.tsv.gz` files, in addition to a `peaks.bed.gz` file.

How do I load this into R and make a Seurat object? Normally there is a matrix, barcodes and features files as output from scATAC-seq 10X data, so how do I handle only having a fragments file instead?

Thank you very much for your help with this!

Edit:

This is the code I would normally run to load the ATAC counts (matrix), barcodes and features and make the Seurat object. However, with this dataset, I do not have the features.tsv file, but a fragments.tsv file instead and so I am unsure how to change my code to accommodate this change in input data.

```r
ATAC_dir <- "~/GSE169246_PDL1/ATAC/"

barcode_path_ATAC <- paste0(ATAC_dir, "barcodes.tsv.gz")
features_path_ATAC <- paste0(ATAC_dir, "features.tsv.gz")
matrix_path_ATAC <- paste0(ATAC_dir, "matrix.mtx.gz")

barcode_names_ATAC <- read.delim(barcode_path_ATAC, 
                            header = FALSE, 
                            stringsAsFactors = FALSE)$V1

feature_names_ATAC <- read.delim(features_path_ATAC, 
                                 header = FALSE, 
                                 stringsAsFactors = FALSE)$V1

mat_ATAC <- readMM(file = matrix_path_ATAC)

colnames(mat_ATAC) <- barcode_names_ATAC
rownames(mat_ATAC) <- feature_names_ATAC


chrom_assay <- CreateChromatinAssay(
  counts = mat_ATAC,
  sep = c(":", "-"),
  genome = 'hg38',
  fragments = "peaks.bed.gz",
  min.cells = 10,
  min.features = 200
)

seurat_ATAC <- CreateSeuratObject(
  counts = chrom_assay,
  assay = "peaks"
)
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Welcome to the site Ebla. Could you kindly describe the code you have written so far to load the data?

Comment: Thank you, I have edited my original post now. I hope it is more clear now, please let me know if I can make it clearer